# DynamoDB Geographic Distribution? (Like CloudFront)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-dynamodb

Amazon DynamoDB is a NoSQL database that I use to store keys that I match with S3. For S3, I use CloudFront to make the download and upload quick for everyone around the world, since CloudFront replicates the data in multiple geographic positions (where there servers are).

Does DynamoDB also have this distribution functionality to make downloading and uploading items quicker (even though it is already blazing fast!) for everyone around the world?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, DynamoDB is not cross-regional. (At least not currently).

One option is to set up DynamoDB in multiple regions and then use [Route53's latency-based routing](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/latency-based-multi-region-routing-now-available-for-aws.html) to automatically direct each user to the closest region.  However, you'll then have multiple databases and your application will have to be designed with a manual sharding technique in mind.

Comment: Thanks, I would prefer not to do that, when a user uploads something it would have to simultaneously upload to like 7 different servers and that would take a while so all other users can access it and it would just take a long time! Is there a way it Route 53 can automatically copy from one region and route the data to other regions?

Comment: I addressed that in my original answer. No.